# Export from Libreoffice Calc to a table LaTeX

Tags: libreoffice, latex

I would like to know if there is a way to transform a sheet of LibreOffice Calc to a table LaTeX. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sure - by hand! Did you mean something more specific?

Comment: Breadcrumbs, in case it's helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/379416/saving-xls-as-csv-with-libreoffice-calc to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146716/importing-csv-file-into-latex-as-a-table

Comment: The best site for this question is [TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).  It has already been discussed quite a bit on that site, as linked in my answer.

Comment: A pretty straight forward way I found is to just copy & paste from Calc to https://www.tablesgenerator.com/

Comment: @dasKeks this seems to be the quickest way, with plenty of options to format the table. thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [Calc2Latex](http://calc2latex.sourceforge.net/).  For a question on how to use this tool, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179208/how-to-use-calc2latex.

For other solutions, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388287/from-libreoffice-calc-to-latex-exporting-tables-and-graphs.